# Banco de Dados Mysql (Insert Into e ordem correta)

Tags: sql

minha dúvida pode parecer boba, mas é algo que eu sempre me perco, como saber a ordem correta do insert into (pra inserir dados na tabela) no banco de dados ? me falaram que é pelas chaves estrangeiras, mas eu não entendi a lógica

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

as insert ficaram nessa ordem:

posto
 tripulação
missao
funcao

status
tipoaeronave
aeronave
escala

Comment: Você tem alguma estrutura de tabelas para colocar junto à pergunta?

Comment: Pior que não, é que eu tinha essa dúvida, dai eu ia colocando as insert e testando qual dava certo

Comment: Então você tem um exemplo?

Comment: eu tenho um banco aqui, mas é muito grande, como vcs querem que eu envie ?

Comment: Tire uma foto ou print do modelo relacional.

Comment: Monta um exemplo básico aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: editei o post com um exemplo

Answer (score 1):

A ordem para você inserir os dados na Tabela seria primeiro pelas tabelas que serão estrangeiras...
Por exemplo, temos a tabela `TIMES` e a tabela `JOGADORES`:

```
CREATE TABLE TIMES 
(
    COD_TIME NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_TIMES PRIMARY KEY (COD_TIME)
);

CREATE TABLE JOGADORES
(
    COD_JOGADOR NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    COD_TIME NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_JOGADORES PRIMARY KEY (COD_JOGADOR),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TIMES_JOGADORES FOREIGN KEY (COD_TIME) REFERENCES TIMES
);
```

No nosso exemplo, cada jogador tem um time: Se começarmos a popular as tabelas pela tabela `JOGADORES`, não haverá nenhum time, porque ainda não adicionamos nenhum registro na tabela `TIMES`.
Na imagem, eu tentei adicionar um `JOGADOR`com o `TIME`de `CODIGO = 1`, porém me deu um erro, que acontece por não existir um `CODIGO = 1`na tabela `TIMES`, ou seja, é como se eu estivesse dizendo que um jogador faz parte de um time que não existe ainda.

[image: INSERINDO JOGADOR SEM EXISTIR O TIME]
A partir do momento que eu criei o `TIME`, dando um `INSERT`na tabela `TIMES`com um registro de `COD_TIME = 1`, ai sim podemos adicionar o `JOGADOR`.

[image: ADICIONANDO JOGADOR]

Ou seja, respondendo a sua pergunta, é preciso iniciar a inserção de registro pelas tabelas que não tem um `FOREIGN KEY`ligadas a elas, a não ser que na tabela estrangeira já possua registros.

No seu caso, na tabela `AERONAVE`, não seria possível adicionar uma `AERONAVE`sem antes adicionar registro em `STATUS` e em `TIPO_AERONAVE`(A não ser que essas colunas aceitem NULL).

Comment: Agora eu entendi, muito obrigado Richard Willian!

Comment: De nada, precisar estamos ai0/